# Converting Series to Pandas DateTime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

D = ["10Aug49","21Jan45","15Sep47","13Jun52"], convert this into pandas date, make sure that year is 1900 not 2000. So far i have this code which converts and prints the pandas date but century is 2000, i want 1900.

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

Dae = pd.Series(["10Aug49","21Jan45","15Sep47","13Jun52"])
x =[]

for i in Dae:
    x = datetime.strptime(i,"%d%b%y")
    print(x)
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(Dae)` or `pd.to_datetime(Dae,format='%d%b%y')` ?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(Dae,format='%d%b%y')

Comment: output:0   2049-08-10
1   2045-01-21
2   2047-09-15
3   2052-06-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel better to correct the year first, then convert to datetime:

```
# identify the year as the last group of digits and prepend 19
corrected_dates = Dae.str.replace('(\d+)$',r'19\1')

# convert to datetime
pd.to_datetime(corrected_dates)
```

Output:

```
0   1949-08-10
1   1945-01-21
2   1947-09-15
3   1952-06-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime(Dae.str.replace('(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)',r'\1-\2-19\3')) Hi can you explain this? It is working though but difficult to understand.

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal see updated answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

Dae = pd.Series(["10Aug49","21Jan45","15Sep47","13Jun52"])
x =[]
new_list = []
for i in Dae:
    i = datetime.strptime(i,"%d%b%y").date()
    if date.today() <= i: 
        i = i.replace(year=i.year - 100)
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)


[datetime.date(1949, 8, 10), datetime.date(1945, 1, 21), datetime.date(1947, 9, 15), datetime.date(1952, 6, 13)]
```