# Pandas fixing Date Index from 2061 to 1961

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Data set:

```
             RPT    VAL 
Date                                                
2061-01-01  15.04   14.96
2061-01-02  14.71   NaN
2061-01-03  18.50   16.88
2061-01-04  10.58   6.63
2061-01-05  13.33   13.25
```

For above data set i am trying to fix the Date Index, such as 2061 should be 1961.

I have tried this which works fine with columns but index, can anyone suggest me how this will work with Index Date:

```
import datetime

def fix_date(x):

    if x.year > 1989:

        year = x.year - 100

    else:

        year = x.year

    return datetime.date(year,x.month,x.day)


Data.Date = Data.Date.apply(fix_date)
Data.head()
```

Comment: What are the original values for date in your data? are they indeed `2061-01-04` or is that converted when using `pd.to_datetime` from something like `01-04-61`

Comment: it was converted pd.to_datetime

Comment: Almost identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61125840/4238408)

Comment: Hi Quang Hoang, that question has series here i have a dataframe with other columns as  well apart from date

Comment: Just treat your `df.index` as the series in that question: `df.index = ....`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Date index a Date column and generate a fake index (could be a simple counter for instance), then apply this filter to the column Date. Finally, you can use the modified Date column as index again.